# Let's use the tag "drm" instead of "digital-rights-management"

Tags: discussion, tags

I propose to use [drm](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drm) instead of [digital-rights-management](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital-rights-management). Reasons:

1. It shorter.
2. It is open to be interpreted as "Digital Restrictions Management", a term of importance for the Free Software movement. (see https://defectivebydesign.org/what_is_drm_digital_restrictions_management)
3. "Digital **Rights** Management" is a loaded term, used to transport a specific meaning (Of course, the same is true for "Digital Restrictions Management". Note that I do *not* propose to use this term as a tag.)

Context: [Does the GNU GPL 3 prohibit DRM?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/974/does-the-gnu-gpl-3-prohibit-drm)

Comment: I would support this, we could possibly add the two alternatives as synonyms and suggest using [tag:drm] in the tag wiki.

Comment: I support the shorter tag, but the backronym 'digital reistrictions management' is stupid!

Comment: I'd actually say this is a bad idea: plenty of people won't know what DRM means, but will know the full phrase. When searching for `digital...` in the tag auto-completion box, this won't come up because the character sequence doesn't match.

Comment: @ArtOfCode That's what synonyms are for.

Comment: @curiousdannii Yes, except the synonym should be to the *longer, clearer* tag - see my answer and the linked Meta.SE post.

Comment: Quite frankly, make them synonyms. We don't need a bunch of short, 3 letter tags: We just need to make them readable and make sense. [digital-rights-management] should be made the parent of [drm]

Comment: "digital-restrictions-management" can't exist because it is too long.

Answer (score 10):

I think that is a good proposal. The reasons:

- [drm](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drm) is short to type for anyone who knows it
- the longer forms can be synonyms, so anyone who knows the longer forms  can still use autocomplete
- the abbreviation is neutral, as the R is interpreted differently

Comment: *"Anyone who knows it"* - What about the people who don't?

Comment: @Zizouz212: For these is point 2: synonyms for the longer forms

Comment: Ahhh, lovely. But point 3... neutral?

Comment: @Zizouz212: Digital Rights Management vs. Digital Restriction Management

Comment: But then wouldn't restrictions fall under rights?

Comment: While this site is in English, *drm* might add a bit of multilingual comprehensibility, as the abbreviation holds for several languages. For instance, the German word for DRM is ... DRM (digitales Rechte-Management).

Answer (score 4):

Let's not.

As I said in a comment above, there are plenty of people who won't know what DRM means, but will know the full phrase. When typing `digital...` in the tag auto-completion box, [drm](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drm) won't come up, but [digital-rights-management](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital-rights-management) will.

Digital *rights* management and digital *restrictions* management are more or less the same thing anyway, with some very minor differences. If it's really necessary, we could synonymize [digital-rights-management](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital-rights-management) and [digital-restriction-management](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital-restriction-management) so that both work with tag auto-completion.

As mentioned in [this Meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114385/262823), we should prefer longer, expressive names over acronyms where possible. Shorter ≠ better.

Comment: The "longer is better" policy has the problem that "digital-restrictions-management" is *too* long. The system has a limit of 25 characters.

Comment: @EricGärtner Hadn't counted the characters, but true. We can still use digital rights management though.

Comment: My proposal is not only about the length. My main point is that I want to make "digtial *restrictions* management" as prominent here as "digital *rights* management". This can only be done by using a *third* form that can mean *both*.

Comment: making [tag:digital-rights-management] a synonym of [tag:digital-restrictions-management] or vice versa might prove to be a bad idea. Making both a synonym for [tag:drm] is sure to be harmless.

Comment: "As I said in a comment above, there are plenty of people who won't know what DRM means, but will know the full phrase." - I am slightly surprised by that claim (although it might be true in this case), given that time and again, catchy, short acronyms tend to become well-known while hardly anyone knows what long form they are supposed to expand to.

Answer (score 2):

"DRM" has five meanings related to Information Technology on Wikipedia's [disambiguation page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRM) and a dozen or so other meanings. No doubt there will be other meanings for the acronym in future.

We definitely shouldn't use DRM, since a question tagged so may have nothing to do with Digital Rights Management.

Comment: Of these meanings only one is relevant in the context of this site.

Comment: @EricGärtner you're wrong, one of them is Direct Rendering Manager which could easily be on-topic: http://dri.freedesktop.org/wiki/DRM. It's part of the Linux project. Also there are many are other meanings for "DRM" that aren't important enough to have a wikipedia article.

Comment: Maybe. But the votes on the question and the answers are clear. The proposal is approved, the tag will be changed.

Comment: Regardless, even if we have a [drm] for this *Direct Rendering Manager*, it likely won't have activity to warrant a tag of its own.

Comment: ***We definitely shouldn't use DRM, since a question tagged so may have nothing to do with Digital Rights Management.*** - In that case, we also have beautiful things called excerpts.